# UIdatepicker showing weekdays

Tags: ios, xcode, date, uipickerview, uidatepicker

I would like to make a datepicker that shows weekdays, date and month.

I got a working datepicker showing month, date and year but I would really like it to show month, day, date

How is this possible? I know I might have to make a custom UIpicker, but how to I make this refer to dates?

Comment: Use NSCalendar class to populate your custom UIPickerView.

Comment: When you say 'date', do you actually mean 'day of month' (1-31)? Month, day, and weekday is a strange combination for the user to select.

Comment: Yes I mean day of month (1-31), it should be Month, day and weekday.. It's an app where you have to fill information for mon-thursday every week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your own picker with a UIPickerView. Create an NSDateFormatter. You can then access the month names and the weekday names from the date formatter. An NSCalendar can be used to obtain the maximum number of days for a month.

The real trick is updating the picker view components as the user selects a value from one of the components. For example, if the user picks a month, you want to update the number of days shown in the day component (or, like a UIDatePicker), grey out invalid days. This is complicated by the fact that you don't have a year so there is no way to properly handle February.

And what do you do when a user picks a given weekday? How should this affect the selected day? Just things to consider.

Comment: Ehm, I think I might have written my question a little bit confusing. I want to show something like this "October - 1. Monday". Would it help to add year? because that shouldn't be a problem for my app

Comment: Picking a month and day requires a year for February. And the only way to know what day of the week a given month and day represent is to also know the year. It's still unclear though. How many components do you want to have in your picker view? Just one that shows all three values (month, day, and weekday). Or two - one for month, one for day? Something else? You should update your question with clearer details.

Comment: @rmaddy if we have a year how can we know the number of days in a month and how we make specific days to be (invalid) grey for example i want to show only sundays?