# UIDatePicker - weekday but no time

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

In `UIDatePicker` there is date mode and date and time mode. The thing is that I want something in between. Basically I need the date mode but also displaying the weekday. Or in other words the date and time mode but without the time options. Is that possible or will I have to use a normal `UIPickerView` and program the options from scratch?

I saw a similar question somebody who just wants to show weekdays instead of dates, but I want the dates, just not the time.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create your own. You can follow the steps that they outline in the post below but you will need to also put the date beforehand. This will be easy to accomplish with a NSDateFormatter.

[UIdatepicker showing weekdays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12959267/uidatepicker-showing-weekdays?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of one that I made. You can add to it and make it have the functionality you want.

[image]

```
//example of use

//inside the class 
var datePicker: DatePicker!

//inside viewDidLoad        
datePicker = DatePicker(date: dateToInitializeDatePickerTo)

extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate {
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        switch(component) {
        case 0:
            return 12
        case 1:
            return datePicker.numberOfYears
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }

      func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        switch(component) {
        case 0:
            return datePicker.longerMonths[row]
        case 1:
            return "\(datePicker.years[row])"
        default:
            return ""
        }
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        switch(component) {
        case 0:
            datePicker.selectedMonth = row
        case 1:
            datePicker.yearsAgo = row
        default:
            break
        }
        yourVariableForTheDate = datePicker.selectedAge
    }
}

    //DatePickerClass.swift
    import Foundation

    class DatePicker {



    let YEARS_FROM_NOW_TILL_THIS_YEAR = 2000

    var type: Int!
    var selectedAge: NSDate {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
        let stringDate = "\(year)-\(stringMonth)-01 01:01"
        let date = formatter.dateFromString(stringDate)!
        return date
    }
    let now = NSDate()

    var years: [Int]!
    var yearsAgo: Int!

    var theMonth: Int!
    var selectedMonth: Int {
        get {
            return theMonth
        }
        set {
            if newValue == -1 {
                theMonth = 11
            } else {
                theMonth = newValue
            }
        }
    }

    private var selectedYear: Int {
        return years[yearsAgo]
    }

    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

    let longerMonths = ["January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    let shorterMonths = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

    var numberOfYears: Int {
        return years.count
    }

    var monthYear: String {
        return  "\(shorterMonth) \(year)"
    }

    var year: Int {
        return years[yearsAgo]
    }

    var longerMonth: String {
        return longerMonths[selectedMonth]
    }

    var shorterMonth: String {
        return shorterMonths[selectedMonth]
    }

    var stringMonth: String {
        var month: String = ""
        if selectedMonth < 9 {
            month.appendContentsOf("0")
        }
        month.appendContentsOf("\(selectedMonth + 1)")
        return month
    }

    init(date: NSDate?) {
        years = generatePickerData()
        if date != nil {
            setAge(date!)
        } else {
            setAge(now)
        }
    }

    func setAge(date: NSDate) {
        selectedMonth = calendar.component(.Month, fromDate: date) - 1
        yearsAgo = (calendar.component(.Year, fromDate: now) - calendar.component(.Year, fromDate: date))
    }

    private func generatePickerData() -> [Int] {
        var yearInts : [Int] = []
        var year = calendar.component(.Year, fromDate: now)
        while year >= YEARS_FROM_NOW_TILL_THIS_YEAR {
            yearInts.append(year)
            year -= 1
        }
        return yearInts
    }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJ7Gg.png
```